# Using jquery to change hyperlinks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a tracking system and am a bit of jquery noob.

Pretend I have this

```
<div class="ads">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
</div>
```

I want to replace the urls with my own, that first go to some page to track the click, such as

http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?url=http://www.google.com

http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com

Obviously with the proper encoding.

I thought I could do something like..

```
$(".ads").find("a").attr("href", "http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?" + $(this).attr("href") );
```

but that doesn't work...and I'm not really sure why

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Be aware that users without JavaScript enabled won't be tracked but I am guessing you have already thought about this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this** is not pointing to the link inside your code.

You may use a function to set the attribute:

```
$(".ads")
.find("a")
 .attr("href", function(i,a)
               {return "http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?"+encodeURIComponent(a)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".ads a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?" + $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

You need to loop through the selection to change attributes relative to themselves, the `.each` method does that :)

Answer (score 0):

My working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZAhkK/

```
$('.ads a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: That's not the same code he posted, you should state that this is a fix :P

P.S. beat you by 30 seconds :D

Comment: Lol, yeah was meant to change it, but yes you did :O

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `this` is not deffined inside the attr() function.

Use `.each()` function instead.

```
$(".ads a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr( 'href', 'http://www.mysite.com/TrackClick/?' + $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

Take a look at

http://jsfiddle.net/H34yX/1/